# Android: Gallery 3D preview

Tags: android, 3d, gallery, preview

I am making an app and is newly learning picture gallery preview. While normal plain listview is ok, I would like to implement in a way as show in the below picture.

May I know how could this be made? Already there already libraries? I have googled something like "3D gallery previewer" or "cylinder view" but cannot find any tutorials for such. Are there any specific term for such layout or any tutorial that can guide me to the right direction?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?